# Why do you need a nonce to verify a form with a PHP SESSION?

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

I am trying to verify that a form was sent from the same server.

I read that a random token can be selected and added to the form as a hidden field and also added to session. Then the php file can validate that the request was sent from this site by comparing the token in the post data to the one in session.

My question is, why do I need to generate a random token at all? Can I not just set a variable in session in the form page, then check to see if that variable is set in the php file and then unset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #1 reason for using such a token is to prevent [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).
The #2 reason is to prevent a user from accidentally submitting the same form twice.

To elaborate on #1, even if you set a session variable that says the user visited the page, it can be faked.  For example, imagine a malicious webpage that contains `<img src='http://example.com/path/to/form.php' /><script>malicious javascript to post form data</script>`.  The image would simulate the user visiting the form and will set the session variable.  The malicious JavaScript would then silently submit form data to your site and you'll have no way of verifying if it was an actual user or an attacker.

Using a simple session variable *might* prevent issue #2, but it does nothing to mitigate CSRF attacks.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But what stops the malicous site making an ajax request to form page, stimulating the PHP SESSION and then reading the value of the hidden field, and then using that value in its own form?

Comment: @ρσݥzση - [Same-origin policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Right, but surely the attacker could still manually access the form page, creating the session info, then view the hidden field in the source, then add that hidden field to a separate form offsite, then post the off-site form. Wouldn't that give a false positive? Then each time the attacker wants to trick the site, they visit the form page and update the token on their form.

Comment: @ρσݥzση - If the attacker visited the form themselves then the token they copy would only be valid for *their own* session.  Trying to use it for another user's session would be invalid.  (The attacker and victim have different sessions, copying CSRF tokens across them doesn't work because the server has an expected value *per user session*.)  The attacker can't modify the victim's session value on the target server (usually stored in cookies), so copy pasting their own CSRF token achieves nothing.